# I'm trying to convert this pattern into asterisks and spaces instead of 0's and 1's

Tags: python

I managed to get the pattern I want to print out, but I can't figure out how to convert these into asterisks. I need the pattern to be an asterisk for the 1s and a space for the 0s, in Python

```
for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            print(int(j + i + 1)%2, end=' ')
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

note that you can index a string like this:

```
>>> " *"[0]
' '
>>> " *"[1]
'*'
```

So just use the computed index as an index for a string made of both space & asterisk characters:

```
print(" *"[(j + i + 1)%2], end=' ')
```